# Avoiding fresh instantiation of modelform fields in django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a modelform with a custom modelchoicefield.

```
class UserModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         return obj.get_full_name()

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    originator = UserModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all().order_by('first_name'),widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['originator']
```

My reading suggests that handling my field this way is overriding any info from the model (for example whether or not it is required) because it's instantiating it from my definition rather than augmenting the model's field.

It seems that to minimise my alteration of fields like this I should be interacting with the init instead (see below)

```
def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
    super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['originator'].queryset=User.objects.all().order_by('first_name')
    self.fields['originator'].widget = forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
```

I understand how to do the queryset and widget assuming that the above is correct. My question is how do I use that custom choicefield. Moreover I'm not even sure if this is the way to do it as it seems a little hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh.. I remember having this problem and not finding a built-in or idiomatic solution. I didn’t come up with a better solution than this decorator (and yes, this is [production code](https://github.com/PACTF/pactf/blob/0cc86dc0ee54ab27214d5a2c0778df8b2787973d/django/ctflex/forms.py#L15)):

```
def model_generated(model):
    """Generate form fields from model fields

    Purpose:
        This decorator lets you have form field attributes like
        `max_length` copied over from a model field while being DRY.

    Usage:
        Decorate a form class with this decorator and set MODEL_GENERATED_FIELDS
        to a list of attribute names you would like to be generated.

    Limitations:
        - Currently, this decorator only supports CharFields.
    """

    def decorator(cls):

        for field_name in cls.MODEL_GENERATED_FIELDS:
            model_field = model._meta.get_field(field_name)

            model_field_type = type(model_field)
            if model_field_type == django_models.CharField:
                form_field_type = forms.CharField
                attributes = {  # (form_attribute, model_attribute, processor)
                    ('label', 'verbose_name', None),
                    ('max_length', None, None),
                    ('min_length', None, None),
                    ('required', 'blank', lambda value: not value),
                }
            else:
                # (Maybe one day this decorator will support more types of fields.)
                raise ValueError("Unknown type of model field: {}".format(model_field_type))

            kwargs = {}
            for form_attribute, model_attribute, processor in attributes:
                if model_attribute is None:
                    model_attribute = form_attribute
                if processor is None:
                    processor = lambda value: value

                if hasattr(model_field, model_attribute):
                    kwargs[form_attribute] = processor(getattr(model_field, model_attribute))

            form_field = form_field_type(**kwargs)
            setattr(cls, field_name, form_field)

            # Register field since we're monkey-patching
            # (Django's meta-class hackery to detect fields only runs the first time the class is declared.)
            cls.base_fields[field_name] = form_field

        return cls

    return decorator
```

So for example I would have:

```
 class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True,
                            verbose_name="Team Name")
    passphrase = models.CharField(max_length=30,
                                  verbose_name="Passphrase")
    ...
```

and:

```
@model_generated(models.Team)
class TeamJoiningForm(forms.Form):
    MODEL_GENERATED_FIELDS = ('name', 'passphrase')
    ...
```

You might adapt and extend the `model_generated` decorator for your own specific needs. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance. Your solution is beyond my expertise in many ways. I am surprised there isn't something built in given it seems to be strongly encouraged

Comment: @Ewanw Try just adding an `elif` branch alongside the `if model_field_type == django_models.CharField` branch and set the variables `form_field_type` and `attributes` appropriately

Comment: And yes, there are many instances where I am surprised something as popular as Django seems to have no good solution to what seem like common problems (and yes, sometimes problems created by their own recommendations!)